# Firebase: how to extract child key value from child node swift

Tags: swift, firebase

How do i extract the ID value of a child (i.e. followerID1, followerID2...)? The firebase is structured as follows:

```
Followers:{
    USER_ID:{
        followerID1 = false;
        followerID2 = true;
        followerID3 = true;
    }
}
```

Im doing the following in xCode, but its showing me the entire node under USER_ID:

```
self.databaseRef.child("Followers").child(self.USER_ID).Value, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
          self.userFollowDump = snapshot
 })
```

Thanks! I am new to firebase :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

- **Swift 3**

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Followers").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
          if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
              for each in userDict{
                  let follwerID = each.0 as! String // Every follwers ID.
              }
          }
      })
  ```

  And if you are looking for the **followerId**'s whose value is **`true`**.

  ```
      FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Followers").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
          if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
              for each in snapDict{

                  print(each.key)
              }
          }
      })
  ```
- **Swift 2**

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Followers").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
   if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
        for each in userDict{
           let follwerID = each.0 as! String // Every follwers ID.
           }
       }
    })
  ```

  But if you are looking for the **followerId**'s whose value is **`true`**

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Followers").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(true).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in
       if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
         for each in snapDict{

              print(each.key)
          }
      }
  })
  ```